# GMSPanoramaViewDelegate not working

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

Learning google map SDK iOS, want to use `GMSPanoramaViewDelegate`, but it is not working.

```swift
class panViewController:UIViewController,UIActionSheetDelegate,GMSPanoramaViewDelegate{
  let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
  var lat_map = 43.649615
  var lng_map = -79.39162
  var panoView : GMSPanoramaView?
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
    panoView!.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat_map,lng_map))

    panoView!.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(panoView!)

  }

 func panoView(pano:GMSPanoramaView!, didTap point:CGPoint!){
    println("working")
  }
}
```

Anyone knows whats wrong here?

Comment: What is not working? Do you get errors? Are the delegate methods not called? Please elaborate.

Comment: when i run any delegate function e.g. didTap, didTapMarker, it has no any response